# Why gods were unable to save them from curses of human beings?

Tags: gods, rishi, curse

No offense but I am unable to understand why Hindu gods seems unable to save themselve from curse. For example:- Ganesha was beheaded by Shiva because he was cursed by Sage Kashayapa, Vishnu was cursed by Sage Bhrigu to take avatar on earth and so on. God is supereme authority. Sages attain power to curse by meditating to god. Then how can they curse god? If god is not able to save himself how can he save us? And does it mean that gods can also do mistakes that's why they suffer due to curse?

Comment: What Puran based masses consider gods like Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh, Indra, Agni etc., are 33 koti positions taken by enlightened souls of previous yugas/times and ruling a particular universe collectively called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyaus Pitra or Jupiter or Guru. True God or Brahman/Purusha is single Omnipresent formless consciousness & unattached to its temporary projection called universe. https://wordandsilence.com/2016/09/21/uma-instructs-the-gods-kena-upanishad/ All curses are temporary and all are one for Highest. "Eka brahma dvitiya nasti",only Brahman exists, nothing else.

Comment: Because the term 'god' is loosely used. The correct term is Devas. Counting from Bhumi as 1, Bhuva as 2, Svarg is 3rd loka where Devas reside. Above that there are 4. Many rishis inhabit these lokas. Rishis are more powerful than Devas. Yes, Devas can make mistakes. You can also become a Deva, and commit mistake, and get cursed and fall back to earth, like Nahusha in Mahabharata. God (with capital G),is Bhagavan/Vishnu. He never makes mistakes. All other Devas are subservient to him, just like a company owner has CEO, Director, Manager etc. working for him

Comment: Lord Shiva was unaffected from curse of Maharshi Bhrigu and Daksha Prajapati. Both gave him curse to be not worshipped by people. And we still worship him. Gods accept the curse as boon asked by rishis. So it is optional for them whether to accept a curse or not. But they mostly accept the curse, to show power of tapas to bhakts. To show that even they also have no choice against tapas. And it is all their leela only. Like devarshi Narad's curse to Vishnu bhagwan was leela for taking avatar as Shree Ram.

Comment: @mar even lord Vishnu was cursed by vrinda and Bhrigu

Comment: @SanatanDarshan - cursed has 2 meanings - cursed to do what you don't want to do, and cursed to do what you already want to do. Even Sri Krishna was "cursed" by Gandhari that Yadava race will be destroyed in 36 years after Mahabharat yudh. Vishnu's curses belong to 2nd category. You can give same logic for curses of other Devas too, but it again depends on which Purana you read. The 18 are divided as 3x6 - for Satva, Rajas, Tamas each. Again, this classification is mentioned in Satvik Purana, so it's up to your guna, as to which Purana you'll like

Comment: @mar **this classification is mentioned in Satvik Purana** about which satvik Purana you are talking? Please provide refrence. I think you are a Vaishnava

Comment: @mar - yes of course I claim to be Vaishnava, even though my lifestyle is total traitor to the sampradaya. Padma Puran 236.18 has the classification. Of course, Shaivites will call this an interpolation. That's OK. Each sect has their own definition of ultimate brahmam. Like I said earlier, either all of them are wrong, or only one of them is right. We all will find out who is right when we have enough tapasya , or when we ourselves attain Moksha.

Comment: @Rudra - AFAIK, Bhrigu did not curse that Shiva will not be worshipped. Bhrigu cursed Brahma that he will not be worshipped. That's why we don't have Brahma temples (barring few exceptions). He cursed Shiva that he will be worshipped in a linga form. Also, no theertha prasad is given in Shiva Aalayas - atleast in traditional south indian temples.

Comment: @ram yes i just confirmed again that maharshi bhrigu didnt curse lord shiva in shiv puran. Btw, which shastra tells story of maharshi bhrigu's curse of getting worshipped in a linga form.